# CircularImageView drawble not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using CircularImageView library to show rounded images in my app.

In my xml file,

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Android Studio isnt showing `@drawable/image`. 'image.jpg' exists in my drawable folder. When I hit `CTRL+SPACE` after `drawable/`, I get no suggestions.

The weird part is the code `android:src="@drawable/image2"` in next ImageView works perfectly, gives suggestions,etc.

I've also tried adding those images in CircularImageView's drawable folder.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding project, doesn't work.

app - > build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appquest.fitterfox"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


          }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
        compile project(':libraries:loadtoast')
        compile project(':libraries:circleimageview')
    }
```

Comment: Instead of adding the project manually, use compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1' to have grade fetch and add the project from maven

Comment: just adding that one line in dependencies, right? alright doing that right now..

Comment: by the way any ideas why did it not work previously?

Comment: image is showing but it is still not giving suggestions...

Comment: I experience that bug with custom views as well. It seems to be a bug in Android studio

Comment: hey that's showing a normal imageview not a rounded one

Comment: It'll show the circular image view in the compiled app running on your device or emulator. The layout editor is still pretty buggy when it comes to custom views. As for why it didn't work before, I can't say for sure. It may be because of how it was added to he project, or something missing from the project build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding your dependencies manually, it's better to fetch them using gradle

```
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
```

will automatically fetch and add circularimageview to your project